# Android - Load image using url from secured server

Tags: android, android-image

Im trying to load images using url in my android application. Ive successfully loaded it and populate my app with images from the web. What i did was, in my image loader, i have this:

```
     try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
```

But then i have also to get image from secure server. like when i access the url of the image from my PC browser, i need to undergo this authentication:

[image]

So, that's why, i modified my ImageLoader. So i added something for the authentication:

```
     try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        String userPass = username+":"+password;
        byte[] encode = Base64.encode(userPass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authentication", "Basic" + encode.toString());
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;


    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
```

The problem is, the image from that secured server cannot be loaded into my application. It just displays my spinning progressbar, since i added it. What area did i make a mistake?  Or how should i improve that part since i'll be loading image url from secured server?
Of course, i know the username and the password.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Btw, the response i get is 400 - Bad Request.